# preg_replace or regex string translation

Tags: php, regex

I found some partial help but cannot seem to fully accomplish what I need.  I need to be able to do the following:

I need an regular expression to replace any 1 to 3 character words between two words that are longer than 3 characters with a match any expression:

For example:

```
walk to the beach ==> walk(.*)beach
```

If the 1 to 3 character word is not preceded by a word that's longer than 3 characters then I want to translate that 1 to 3 letter word to `'<word> ?'`

For example:

```
on the beach ==> on ?the ?beach
```

The simpler the rule the better (of course, if there's an alternative more complicated version that's more performant then I'll take that as well as I eventually anticipate heavy usage eventually).

This will be used in a PHP context most likely with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/preg_replace). Thus, if you can put it in that context then even better!

By the way so far I have got the following:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '(.*)', $string); 
$string = preg_replace('/\b(\w{1,3})(\.*)\b/', '${1} ?', $string);
```

but that results in:

```
walk to the beach ==> 'walk(.*)to ?beach'
```

which is not what I want. `'on the beach'` seems to translate correctly.

Comment: By the way so far I have got the following:

$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '(.*)', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/\b(\w{1,3})\(\.\*\)\b/', '${1} ?', $string);

but that results in:
walk to the beach ==> 'walk(.*)to ?beach'

which is not what I want.  'on the beach' seems to translate correctly.

Comment: you should add things like this to question instead of commenting

Comment: m.buettner that was a comment to my own questions to clarify what I already have working.

Comment: yes, but I recommend that you edit your question instead and add your own effort to the question itself

Comment: @ccolon:  Better edit your question instead of hiding the "what I've tried" part in comments. I edited your question now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you will need two replacements for that. Let's start with the first requirement:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\w{4,})(?: \w{1,3})* (?=\w{4,})/', '$1(.*)', $str);
```

Of course, you need to replace those `\w` (which match letters, digits and underscores) with a character class of what you actually want to treat as a word character.

The second one is a bit tougher, because matches cannot overlap and lookbehinds cannot be of variable length. So we have to run this multiple times in a loop:

```
do
{
    $str = preg_replace('/^\w{0,3}(?: \w{0,3})* (?!\?)/', '$0?', $str, -1, $count);
} while($count);
```

Here we match everything from the beginning of the string, as long as it's only up-to-3-letter words separated by spaces, plus one trailing space (**only if** it is not already followed by a `?`). Then we put all of that back in place, and append a `?`.

**Update:**

After all the talk in the comments, here is an updated solution.

After running the first line, we can assume that the only less-than-3-letter words left will be at the beginning or at the end of the string. All others will have been collapsed to `(.*)`. Since you want to append all spaces between those with `?`, you do not even need a loop (in fact these are the only spaces left):

```
$str = preg_replace('/ /', ' ?', $str);
```

(Do this right after my first line of code.)

This would give the following two results (in combination with the first line):

```
let us walk on the beach now go => let ?us ?walk(.*)beach ?now ?go
let us walk on the beach there now go => let ?us ?walk(.*)beach(.*)there ?now ?go
```

Comment: The first one worked!  The second one I'm not sure how $count is defined.  What is $count?

Comment: @ccolon `$count` is an output parameter. Since in PHP you don't need to declare variables ahead of time, you can use it within the function for the first time (it is only used within those 4 lines - no need to assign some value ahead of time). `preg_replace` will then fill the variable with the number of replacements that was done. Thus, the loop will continue until no further replacements are made.

Comment: m.buettner -- couldn't get the second one (the loop) to work.

Comment: @Ωmega point taken for the first one. What's wrong with the second one?

Comment: ...not that I am complaining, but in what respect does this answer improve on my approach? :)

Comment: @Ωmega, yes I saw your answer and from the question I assumed that your behavior for the 2nd snippet is not what's intended but mine is ;)

Comment: @ccolon just out of curiosity, what should happen to less-than-3-letter words that are not **followed** by more-than-3-letter words?

Comment: huh?  like "go to"?  I suspect that will translate to "go ?to" and whatever the search returns is it.  This solution I have right now is not a perfect one but one that will evolve.  Ultimately, I want the search to be as intelligently as possible to mimic natural language matching.  To start with what I've thought of already is good enough.  But knowing how programming works in a few days from now I will think of something else and will improve upon the solution at that point :-)

Comment: By the way, if you have a better natural language matching expression that can better select a vacation rental based on its description (and other things) then I like to hear about it.  Regular Expressions are not my strength even though I've tried to make sense of them!  It takes me a lot of trial and error to put one together when it takes you guys a few minutes to do it.  I'm jealous :-)

Comment: @ccolon I meant things like `walk on the beach now go` (ignore the fact that it makes no sense). What happens to the last two spaces?

Comment: m.buettner, ok, I'll try to do a trim() before the final MySQL REGEXP is sent.  Maybe that will increase the chances of matching something, unless you can change the regex pattern to somehow deal with it.

Comment: @ccolon I think we are still not talking about the same thing. from your specification `let us walk on the beach now go` should result in `let ?us ?walk(.*)beach now go`. But don't you actually want `let ?us ?walk(.*)beach ?now ?go` ?

Comment: m-buettner, ok, I see what you are saying.  I was loosely (and hopefully) trying to eliminate insignificant words from the search.  That's why I decided to replaced up to 3 letter words from the middle.  I thought I would keep their significance if these were in front since otherwise too many irrelevant records would be matched.

Comment: Having said the previous comment, I still rather err in the case of returning irrelevant records than not return a relevant one.  Thus, I need to be fairly careful on how strict I make the matching which is why I focus on loosely matching, instead.

Comment: hey, m-buettner, I noticed I focused on the front/middle 1-3 letter words in my comments and not in the trailing 1-3 letter words as you've been trying to point out.  Yes, I actually need to translate those to "... ?now ?go" as you point out (perhaps eliminating the last " ?" from your example.  Could you please post an updated pattern to do that?

Comment: m-buettner, what happened between "beach there"?  I would have expected (.*) there.  Didn't happen.

Comment: ah okay. in the first line, change that `+` to a `*` (I'll change it in the answer now)

Comment: @ccolon I just realized, this makes the second step a lot easier: `$str = preg_replace('/ /', ' ?', $str);`

Comment: Just accepted the answer...sorry had some power outages due to hurricane Sandy :-)  Not sure what the negative vote is about...I wasn't allowed to vote!

Comment: No worries, I didn't imply that you downvoted the question ;). All the best during Sandy!

Comment: hey, m.buettner, given input "spa", the pattern above is resulting in a MySQL's query containing "description REGEXP 'spa'" which matches things like Spanish.  How can I change the pattern to only match full word matches (i.e., return description if and only if it has something like "...spa, ..." but do not return description if it has "...speak spanish..."?

Comment: of course, if the input is "get a massage at a good spa" that should result in matching "massage(.*)good(.*)spa" where massage, good, and spa all match full words.

Comment: @ccolon can you simply add `\b` before and after `spa`? `\b` marks a word boundary, so it will match between word and non-word characters and is usually how you check for full words. however, this comment section is not the right place to discuss it, you should probably ask a new question if my suggestion doesn't do it ;) (and if you have any further queries, too)

Comment: I think I got it by enclosing pattern words in [[:<:]] [[:>:]].  Thanks